# Custom Login Page Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to create a custom login page template for my Wordpress website so I have used the code from codex (https://codex.wordpress.org/Customizing_the_Login_Form) but I don't know how to change the redirect when the user put wrong username or password. It sends the user to the default wp-login page.
How can I redirect the user to my custom login page but with an error message?

P.S.: I am a self-taught coder and I know almost nothing about PHP.

```
<?php  
/** 
 * Template Name: login page 
 */  
?> 

<?php get_header(); ?> 


<?php
    if ( ! is_user_logged_in() ) { // Display WordPress login form:
        $args = array(
            'redirect' => admin_url(),
            'form_id' => 'student-loginform',
            'label_username' => __( 'Username' ),
            'label_password' => __( 'Password' ),
            'label_remember' => __( 'Lembrar-me' ),
            'label_log_in' => __( 'Log In' ),
            'remember' => true,
            'echo' => true,
    );

    wp_login_form( $args );



    } else { // If logged in:
        wp_loginout( home_url() ); // Display "Log Out" link.
        echo " ";
    }
?>  




<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

To handle this problem we have the following cases:

1. User default wp-login page (*if use not admin we need redirect to home page, code put file functions.php theme your*):

   ```
   add_action('admin_init', 'redirect_dashboard');  
   function redirect_dashboard() {  
   if (!current_user_can('administrator') && is_admin() && !wp_doing_ajax()) {  
       wp_redirect(get_bloginfo('url'));  
       exit;  
       }
   }
   ```
2. Redirect when the user put wrong username or password (*can empty data username or password, login failed code put file functions.php theme your*):

   ```
   function login_failed() {  
       $login_page  = home_url( '/login/' );  
       wp_redirect( $login_page . '?login=failed' );  
       exit;  
   }

   add_action( 'wp_login_failed', 'login_failed' );  
   function verify_username_password( $user, $username, $password ) {  
       $login_page  = home_url( '/login/' );  
       if( $username == "" || $password == "" ) {  
           wp_redirect( $login_page . "?login=empty" );  
           exit;  
       }
   }
   ```
3. Redirect when user not login (*put code in header.php theme check user login*):

   ```
   if (!is_user_logged_in()) {  
       wp_redirect(home_url('/login/'));  
       exit;  
   }
   ```

Comment: Thank @Daniel James